# No such file or directory when chown on newly created directory

Tags: directory, chown

I'm a very new Ubuntu user (14.04 LTS) and this is my first question here.

I am trying to follow the instructions from this Reddit thread about mounting an NTFS hard disk to use as a Plex media library (https://www.reddit.com/r/PleX/comments/2opw25/super_annoying_permissions_issue/cmqjcml)

After creating (with sudo) the /media/samsung directory (in my case) I cannot change the owner as the directory cannot be found. The casing is correct. Here is output showing the directory and the error...

---

```
$ dir
Desktop    Downloads         media  Pictures          Public     Videos
Documents  examples.desktop  Music  plexmedialibrary  Templates

$ cd media
~/media$ dir
samsung
~/media$ cd ../..
/home$ sudo chown paul:paul /media/samsung
[sudo] password for paul: 
chown: cannot access ‘/media/samsung’: No such file or directory
/home$
```

---

What is wrong here? I'm finding Ubuntu very frustrating so far. TIA.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use 'chmod' on an NTFS (or FAT32) partition?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition)

Comment: "After creating (with sudo) the /media/samsung directory". When did you do that?(it is not in the commands you supplied).

Comment: @Rinzwind aside from the typo, `chmod`/`chown` on an NTFS in itself is not going to work, hence the possible dupe.

Comment: Yes, I know. But it is not an answer to the problem; it is an answer to what user the wants. So I am in doubt _O-

Comment: @Rinzwind Another [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), I suppose.

Comment: I created the media and media\samsung folders previous to this step. That was successful. the script I included here was just to demonstrate the apparent incongruity between the existence of the folder and the error message. I shall try elmer82's proposed answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake you made is to mix up `/media/samsung` with `~/media/samsung` notice the `~`

The `~` sign refers to your home folder location for example `/home/$USER/`  when you stated `~/media/samsung` you were actually typing `/home/$USER/media/samsung`

You could also use `sudo chown paul:paul ./media/samsung` the `.` means from current folder (or something like it) but this will set the ownership for the folder located at `/home/$USER/media/samsung`.

Comment: Thank you. I shall try it tomorrow evening. It's late here now.

Comment: thank you. I am a little less frustrated today and looking forward to learning more